# Oracle : Compare CLOB Data across two databases using Database Link

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-administration

I have two Oracle 11gR2 databases having CLOB data. The two databases have identical schema.

I need to compare contents of tables which have CLOB columns using database link.

Though there is DBMS_CRYPTO package which can calculate HASH, but that can result in HASH collisions.

What would be best way to compare contents in such case ?

Answer (score 0):

Example table structure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE X.TEXT_TABLE
(   ID VARCHAR2,
  NAME VARCHAR2,
  TEXT CLOB
);
```

You can use an Oracle global temporary table to pull the CLOBs over to your local instance temporarily. You can then use the DBMS_LOB.COMPARE function to compare the CLOB columns.

If this query returns any rows, the CLOBs are different (more or less characters, newlines, etc) or one of the rows exists in only one of the instances.

```
--Create temporary table to store the text in
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE X.TEMP_TEXT_TABLE
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
AS
   SELECT * FROM X.TEXT_TABLE@REMOTE_DB;

--Use this statement if you need to refresh the TEMP_TEXT_TABLE table
INSERT INTO X.TEMP_TEXT_TABLE
SELECT * FROM X.TEXT_TABLE@REMOTE_DB;

--Do the comparision   
SELECT DISTINCT
       TARGET.NAME TARGET_NAME
      ,SOURCE.NAME SOURCE_NAME
      ,DBMS_LOB.COMPARE (TARGET.TEXT, SOURCE.TEXT) AS COMPARISON
  FROM    (SELECT ID, NAME, TEXT FROM X.TEMP_TEXT_TABLE) TARGET
       FULL OUTER JOIN
          (SELECT ID, NAME, TEXT FROM X.TEXT_TABLE) SOURCE
       ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID
 WHERE DBMS_LOB.COMPARE (TARGET.TEXT, SOURCE.TEXT) <> 0
    OR  DBMS_LOB.COMPARE (TARGETTEXT, SOURCE.TEXT) IS NULL;
```

Note depending on the size of your tables this could use significant IO to pull the tables over.